# Is it possible to design a control of my own in c#

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I would like to design a richTextBox control of my own with rounded rectangular edges or liek some other is it possible to customize this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

Add a new UserControl and then inherit from the existing RichTextBox.  You will have to override the onPaint method to create a richtextbox with rounded corners.

This article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/RoundedCornerTextbox.aspx) may help you.  It is based on a TextBox control (in VB) rather than a RichTextBox Control.

Answer (score 1):

yes by using the user Control you can also inherits an  existing control and changing it